# Example of Additive function but not linear from $C\to C$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have an example of  function which have homogenity but not additive .but now i want function which is Additive but not homogeneity (not linear)

help me thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(a+ib)= b+ia$ is additive but not homogeneous. For example try comparing $if(i)$ and $f(ii)=f(-1)$.

Over $\mathbb{R}$, things are a lot more complicated. By using the axiom of choice, it can be shown that there do exist functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is additive but not linear. It can be shown that such functions are nowhere continuous and they are unbounded on all non-empty open intervals. For more information about such functions, I'd recommend this wikipedia article on [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) and this excellent [Mathematics Stack Exchange Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Comment: I want example over field R

Comment: @CloudJR I have edited my answer to include some information about the case when $f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.