# Is the scaling property necessary for functions to be linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

A function $L: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as linear if:

1. $L(\mathbf{x+y}) = L(\mathbf{x}) + L(\mathbf{y})$
2. $L(c\mathbf{x}) = cL(\mathbf{x})$, $c\in\mathbb{R}$

My question is whether property 2 is necessary or if it is derivable from 1? Or if there are functions such that property 1 is satisfied but not 2. For example, if we switch $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, it's easy to see that the conjugate function satisfies 1 but not 2.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806025/example-of-additive-function-but-not-linear-from-c-to-c) may help.

Comment: We have $L(x+x)=L(x)+L(x)=2L(x)$.